# Can't get FCM push notifications from my server on iOS (working on Android)

Tags: python, ios, swift, django, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm new to iOS/Swift and can't get push notifications working. I have configured my server backend to push notifications to my app when some action happens. I have configured a data notification trough FCM because I need some custom data in the notification to open one activity/view or another. This is the code used to send the notification (python/django):

```py
registration_id = profiletarget.device_token
    message_title = "Ha llegado tu turno"
    message_body = "Entra y escribe en el relato para el que estás en cola"
    data_message = {
        "title" : "¿Listo para escribir?",
        "body" : "Ha llegado tu turno para escribir en el relato. Recuerda que tienes un minuto para aceptar tu turno y 3 para escribir.",
        "bookid" : booktarget.pk,
        "multimediaurl" : multimediaused.url
        }
    result = push_service.notify_single_device(registration_id=registration_id, data_message=data_message)
```

Everything inside this code is working, because I get them correctly on Android. But on iOS... I can't get it working.

I have get the notifications token, I have post it to my server, I have use the notification sender on FCM console to send test push notifications (the iPhone get them), but not the ones from my custom method, It doesn't show anything. Is anything wrong in the server method or am I missing something?

This is the swift code:

```swift
import UIKit
import KeychainSwift
import Firebase
import FirebaseMessaging

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, MessagingDelegate {

    var window : UIWindow?;
    var storyboard : UIStoryboard?;
    var token = ""
    let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        self.storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main);
        UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "PT Sans", size: 12)!], for: .normal)
        UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "PT sans", size: 12)!], for: .selected)
        let keychain = KeychainSwift()
        token = keychain.get("token") ?? ""
        if (token != ""){
            print("log-token: ", token)
            print("log-redirection: ", "no redirection needed!")
            FirebaseApp.configure()
            Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
              // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
              UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

              let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
              UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })
            } else {
              let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
              UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
              application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
            }

            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        } else {
            print("log-token: ", "noToken")
            print("log-redirection: ", "redirection to LoginController")
            window?.rootViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginView");
        }
        return true
    }

    func application(
      _ application: UIApplication,
      didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data
    ) {
      let tokenParts = deviceToken.map { data in String(format: "%02.2hhx", data) }
      let token = tokenParts.joined()
      print("Device Token: \(token)")
        postNotificationToken(token: token)
    }

    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
      print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")

      let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken]
      NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)
      // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
      // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
    }

    func postNotificationToken(token:String) {
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://myurl?myparam="+token)!)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("Bearer "+self.token, forHTTPHeaderField: "myauth")

        let session = URLSession.shared
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { data, response, error -> Void in
            let httpURLResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse;
            if (httpURLResponse?.statusCode == 200){
                let string = String.init(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
                print(string)
            } else {
                print(httpURLResponse?.statusCode)
            }
        })

        task.resume()
    }



    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
        print("Received data message: \(remoteMessage.appData)")
    }

    @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)
    {
        completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
    }


    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle


}
```

This are my target capabilities:

[image: Project target capabilities]

And this is my key for APN notifications in my developer account:

[image: APN Key]

With FCM console, notifications are Ok:

[image: FCM Console]

Thanks for reading this long post. Anything will help!

Comment: Well, your method has named as `func postNotificationToken(token:String)` and you wrote that "I have post it to my server", but I see `request.httpMethod = "GET"`. it bothers me.

Comment: yeah, i write "post" not as http method, I just say it as a synonim of send. The token is sended to server via get request as a param in the url. And the token is correctly stored in the database (i have checked it is the same in the xcode print and database)

Comment: Yes, The GoogleService-info.plist is in the project and push notifications is added to capabilities. As I said in the post, the default test notification from FCM console works fine (so it recives it)... the one that doesn't works is my custom one

Comment: There could be something wrong with the push notifications certificate you created.Or something might have gone wrong when you added that certificate to your project in FCM. Would suggest debug / test it by sending notifications directly from FCM Console. If that does work then the problem is with your server code else recreate the push cer. and again add it to FCM Project.

Comment: Hi and thanks. As I said, seding the FCM Console notification works fine, but I can't get it working with my custom notification (that works on android), nothing is received on iphone with the custom one, but everything ok with the FCM console one.

Comment: Did you create push notification certificates from apple developer and add in to Firebase properly?

Comment: Thanks. Yes I did, so the FCM console notifications are working

Comment: I don't see method `func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)`. Could you add and check `print(userInfo)`. Do you have any information at Xcode debug console?

Comment: I Will try now. I have seen many other posts to try get this working. So maybe I have deleted some methods in my way... I'll post print(userinfo) if it gets called.

Comment: I can't test that now because the iPhone owner mate is away. Will test it  by the end of the day and post the result. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I have it working mixing some of the answers and some code found on other posts. First of all, I am using APN key, not APN certificates.

Second, I'm checking what OS has the user to I have to send the notification (iOS/Android) so I can configure different notification structure. This is the notification system in python/django using PyFCM library and sending the iOS notification as alert, as I found on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58194041/does-fcm-support-the-new-apns-push-type-for-ios-13) :

```py
if devicetype == "and":
        registration_id = profiletarget.device_token
        message_title = "default-title"
        message_body = "default-body"
        data_message = {
            "title" : "title",
            "body" : "body",
            "bookid" : booktarget.pk,
            "multimediaurl" : multimediaused.url
            }
        result = push_service.notify_single_device(registration_id=registration_id, data_message=data_message)
    else:
        registration_id = profiletarget.device_token
        message_title = "title"
        message_body = "body"
        data_message = {
            "bookid" : booktarget.pk,
            "multimediaurl" : multimediaused.url,
            }
        result = push_service.notify_single_device(registration_id=registration_id,
                                   message_title=message_title,
                                   message_body=message_body,
                                   data_message=data_message,
                                   extra_kwargs={"apns_push_type": "alert"}
                                   )
```

In Xcode I only had to ad capabilities for push notifications and background mode - remote notifications, as posted in the question pic.

In code, I missed some part of firebase tutorial corresponding to this methods:

```swift
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
      // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
      // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
      // TODO: Handle data of notification

      // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
      // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

      // Print message ID.
      if let messageID = userInfo["body"] {
        print("Notif metod 1")
//        gotoWritting(bookid: messageID)
      }

      // Print full message.
      print("Notif metod 1")
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
      // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
      // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
      // TODO: Handle data of notification

      // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
      // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

      // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo["body"]{
        print("Notif metod 2")
//        gotoWritting(bookid: messageID)
      }

      // Print full message.
      print(userInfo["bookid"]!)
        gotoWritting(bookid: Int(userInfo["bookid"]! as! String) ?? 90)
      completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }
```

The second one is the one is getting triggered by the notification click (background, foreground and app closed...) and once its clicked, I can redirect the user with some notification params.

I cant test on previous version, but hope it works on iOS 9 to (If you know if that works or not, let me know please).

Thanks to everyone who helped!

Answer (score 0):

Did you configured your app certificate with push notifications?

[image: iOS Push notifications]

Also you will need to configure the project in Xcode select one of your targets and go to ->  **SignIn and capabilities** and **add** the **Push Notifications** capability for each target, the pushes ain't working in the simulator visible, but the method *didReceiveRemoteNotification* is triggered, you can debug with some log or breakpoint if you are receiving them.

Comment: I did, will upload the picture. The debug console shows me this message from notifications: `[Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM012002] Error in application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: remote notifications are not supported in the simulator` so i though it can't even get triggered. Will edit with picture of capabilities.

Comment: It shows nothing on console when my server send the notification... Also notice that I have two funcs that are supposed to get the registration token... but two responses are different. The first one 64 chars and the second one 152... Witch one is the right one? I have tried both... FCM Console worked, but I haven't to upload the token there, so maybe there is the problem (that i was sending a bad token...)

Comment: Okey, I have see what you was saying with your picture. Should certificates be 0? or have I to create one and put it somewhere?

Comment: You have to create your certificate for SSL in your own server, I have always configured it with Firebase Analytics, so not needed afaik.

Comment: It doesn't work with the apn key? FCM give me the two options... And said it was better with apn key

Answer (score 0):

[image: Change The info plist according to this]

> Try to send this type of custom formate with custom payload
>
> note : this is node.js code

```
    let message = {
    tokens: iosTokens,
    notification: {
        title: "title",
        body: "",
    },data = {
    "title" : "¿Listo para escribir?",
    "body" : "Ha llegado tu turno para escribir en el relato. Recuerda que tienes un minuto para aceptar tu turno y 3 para escribir.",
    "bookid" : booktarget.pk
    },apns : {
        payload: {
            aps: {
                mutableContent: true,
                contentAvailable: true,
                category: "CustomSamplePush",
                alert: {
                    launchImage: "imageURL.jpeg",
                    sound: "default"
                }
            }

        }
    }
};
```

Comment: yeah... the problem is recreating that structure with python fcm library methods... That apns payload should replace my actual `data-message`?

Comment: Thanks, will try. now and post simulator console debug

Comment: yeah, that was what i was saying before about recreating in python. Wil try. Thanks!